# Set text selection color for Light High Contrast

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

How to set text selection color to webview `textfield` in an extension to VS Code.

**Specifications**:

1. VS COde **version 1.67**.
2. For theme **Light High Contrast**.

I have this at the moment (apps.css):

```css
.vscode-high-contrast .vscode-light .oj-text-field .oj-text-field-input::selection,
.vscode-high-contrast .vscode-light .oj-text-field .oj-combobox-input::selection,
.vscode-high-contrast .vscode-light .oj-text-field .oj-select-chosen::selection {
    color: var(--vscode-editor-selectionForeground);
    background-color: var(--vscode-editor-selectionBackground);
}

.oj-text-field .oj-text-field-input::selection,
.oj-text-field .oj-combobox-input::selection,
.oj-text-field .oj-select-chosen::selection {
    color: var(--vscode-menu-selectionForeground);
    background-color: var(--oj-core-bg-color-selected);
}

.oj-hicontrast .oj-text-field .oj-text-field-input::selection,
.oj-hicontrast .oj-text-field .oj-combobox-input::selection,
.oj-hicontrast .oj-text-field .oj-select-chosen::selection {
    color: var(--vscode-menu-selectionForeground);
    background-color: var(--vscode-selection-background);
}
```

I need to stay in this version of VS Code, I know that this issue is not present in later versions. But I need it to be compatible with this version as well.